# Tkinter: How to modify/remove "View--> Enter Full Screen" menu item under MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, menu, fullscreen

As soon as I add a "View" menu in Tkinter under MacOS, this menu will include a "Enter Full Screen" item by default. I would like to modify or even entirely remove this. Any ideas on how to do this?

My first attempt was to simply add another item with that name (similar to how you modify the "Apple" menu in Tkinter):

```
self.view_menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.view_menu, label="View")
    self.view_menu.add_command(label="Enter Full Screen",
                               command=self.toggle_fullscreen,
                               accelerator=f"F11")
```

But this just results in two items with the same name:
[image]